# function foldByKey : Using an integer inside a tuple for calculation giving "int object not subscriptable"

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I am new to databricks and pyspark. While experimenting with a few things that I have learned till now I faced the following problem. Any help would be great.

I have an RDD like (student name, subject, marks). I am trying to add the marks of all the subjects of a particular student and produce an output like (student name, total marks) using foldByKey.

My code:

```
newRdd = sc.parallelize([
  ("Joseph","maths",4),("Joseph","science",1)])

def addFunc(accumulator, element):
  return accumulator + element[1]

newRdd.map(lambda t: (t[0],(t[1],t[2]))).foldByKey(0, addFunc).collect()
```

Getting an error **"

> int object is not subscriptable

for the `return` statement in function `addFunc`. I think it's caused by the `element[1]` inside `addFunc`

I thought that `foldByKey` will send the tuples `("maths",4)` and `("science",1)` to `addFunc` parameter `element` and so i need to use `element[1]` to extract the marks from the tuple and add it to the `accumulator`

If I use just `return accumulator + element` without the subscript then I get an error

```
TypeError : unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

maybe because `element` receives the tuples `("maths",4)` and `("science",1)`

If I use `return accumulator + element[0]` then I get the error

`TypeError : unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`

which I think is because in this case `element[0]` extracts the subject names as strings.

An explanation of how foldByKey iterates through the rdd and how parameters are passed to addFunc will be very helpful in understanding why I am getting the error

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
rdd1 = newRdd.map(lambda x : (x[0],x[2]))
rdd2 = rdd1.foldByKey(0,lambda x,y: x+y)
rdd2.collect()
```

> > [('Joseph', 5)]

Comment: Thanks Omar for the answer. It did work, But I am still curious why it didnt work the way I wrote it initially. Failing to see the flaw still. It would be great if you can explain that please.

Answer (score -1):

You are getting this error because foldByKey return type should be the same as the input RDD element type(By definition). You are passing a tuple RDD to foldByKey and you want an integer as its return value. What you are trying to achieve can be done through aggregateByKey() because it can return a different type than its RDD input type.

For the time being, you can follow Omar's answer as its input RDD element type and foldByKey return type are same.